# I have a LINQ query a Guid field ToString() is giving me error when is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am calling a function to do a select in LINQ and the line **UserKey = e.user_key.ToString()**, is a GUID field that I convert to String and it is giving me an error when there are null fields, does anyone know how I can solve it?

```
internal static IQueryable<UserAccount> SelectDTO(this IQueryable<UserAccount> query)
        {
            return query.Select(e => new UserAccount()
            {
                Id = e.user_id,
                FirstName = e.first_name,
                LastName = e.last_name,
                MiddleInt = e.middle,
                UserKey = e.user_key.ToString(),
               
            });
        }
```

Comment: Which error do you get (message + type) and which type of LINQ is this? If Entity Framework then please add a tag for the exact version. Then maybe you'll get less premature answers.

Answer (score 1):

assuming UserKey is a string type, try this

```
 UserKey = e.user_key==null? "" : e.user_key.ToString()
```

or if you are using net 6 with nullables

```
UserKey = e.user_key==null? "" : ((Guid) e.user_key).ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you for some reason I keep having errors

Comment: What error do you have now? What type is UserKey ?

Comment: UserKey = e.user_key?.ToString() ?? ""

Comment: Hello thank you for you help yes I used but it keeps giving me errors I don't know what it could be, I used as well   UserKey = e.user_key==null? "" : e.user_key.ToString() and it but I'm not sure what it could be

Comment: @GermanBernal You have to show the error if you need some help.

Comment: Yes I know the problem is in an API and it does not have an catch exception so I will try to see how can I print out the error to see what happens, the error that I'm getting it won't help because is a general error  but to be honest I thought that with your line of code will work but it keeps not working so I will see if I can catch the error and share.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Convert.ToString()` method:

```
internal static IQueryable<UserAccount> SelectDTO(this IQueryable<UserAccount> query)
{
    return query.Select(e => new UserAccount()
    {
        Id = e.user_id,
        FirstName = e.first_name,
        LastName = e.last_name,
        MiddleInt = e.middle,
        UserKey = Convert.ToString(e.user_key),
       
    });
}
```

Since `Convert.ToString()` handles null, while `ToString()` doesn't.

`Convert.ToString()` doesn't need to presume the object is not null (as it is a static method on the Convert class), but instead will return `String.Empty` if it is null.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to use the "Elvis" operator.

Here how:

```
var guid = (Guid?)null;
var text = guid?.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(text == null);
```

That operator say, if the variable is `null` then return `null`, but otherwise call the `.ToString()` method.

That prints out `True` on the console.

So, in your code, it would look like this:

```
internal static IQueryable<UserAccount> SelectDTO(this IQueryable<UserAccount> query)
{
    return query.Select(e => new UserAccount()
    {
        Id = e.user_id,
        FirstName = e.first_name,
        LastName = e.last_name,
        MiddleInt = e.middle,
        UserKey = e.user_key?.ToString(),
    });
}
```

Yes, it's just the addition of a `?`.

Comment: Thank you yes for some reason it does not like the  "?"